# Getting an array of table categorized and cumulated

Tags: android, arrays, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a table that store recent information about Department and bills. My goal is to find the last seven days activities from today date, categorize them by the Department and add up the price and return them as an array.

```
mysql> select * from Item;
+----+------------+--------------+
| ID | Department | Price | Date
+----+------------+--------------+
|  1 | DELL       | 20    | 04/01/2019
|  2 | HP         | 15    | 04/16/2019
|  3 | DELL       | 30    | 03/15/2019
|  4 | ACER       | 15    | 04/16/2019
|  5 | ASUS       | 60    | 04/15/2019
|  6 | HP         | 15    | 04/14/2019
|  7 | DELL       | 30    | 03/30/2019
|  8 | ACER       | 15    | 01/16/2019
|  9 | ASUS       | 60    | 02/15/2019
+----+------------+----------+
```

So far I ordered the table by date:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + Projects_TABLE + " ORDER BY " + PRO_DATE + " DES", null);
```

and compared the today date minus 7 days stored inside the table, but I don't know how to return every Department accord in the seven days with an added price
for example, wanted results of an array:

```
Today Date is 04/16/2019
+----+------------+----------+
| ID | Department | Price 
+----+------------+----------+
|  1 | HP         | 30 
|  2 | ACER       | 15
+----+------------+----------+
```

Here is My code

```
 public  ArrayList<DetailedProject_GS> DB_Display_The_Progress_Weakly() {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase ();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + Projects_TABLE + " ORDER BY " + PRO_DATE + " DES", null);
        ArrayList<DetailedProject_GS> ProjectsArchive = new ArrayList<>();
        Calendar EndTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        cursor.moveToFirst ();
        while (cursor != null && cursor.getCount () > 0 && !cursor.isAfterLast ()) {
            try {
                SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new 
 SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd/MM/yyyy" , Locale.ENGLISH);

                String currentDateandTime = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                c.setTime(simpleDateFormat.parse(currentDateandTime));
                c.add(Calendar.DATE, -7);

                EndTime.setTime(sdf.parse(cursor.getString (cursor.getColumnIndex (PROJECT_H_ENDTIME)) ));// all done
                if (EndTime.after(c)){

                    //Adding CODE HERE
                    ProjectsArchive.add(data);
                }else{

                }
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            cursor.moveToNext ();
        }
        cursor.close();
        sqLiteDatabase.close ();
        return ProjectsArchive;
    }
```

Comment: What is this MySql or SQLite?

Comment: SQLiteDatabase.

Comment: Then change the format of the dates to YYYY-MM-DD so they are comparable. SQLite is not that flexible with dates.

Comment: how do I return an array categorized and cumulated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the format of the dates to `YYYY-MM-DD`, then all you need is `group by department`:

```
select 
  department, 
  sum(price) price 
from item
where date >= datetime('now', '-7 day')
group by department
```

With the current format of the dates, first you must convert it to `YYYY-MM-DD`:

```
select 
  department, 
  sum(price) price 
from item
where substr(date, 7) || '-' || substr(date, 1, 2) || '-' || substr(date, 4, 2) >= datetime('now', '-7 day')
group by department
```

Comment: I added the code I wrote so far, the comparison of dates return any row that is between 7 days, the issue here is it return them all as individual rows I want them categorized and cumulated. however, I get what you mean with SQL database i will fix it next.

Comment: `group by department` categorizes the rows by department and sum(price) adds all the values in column price.